# Vue.js removing element from list removes always the last item of the for

Tags: vue.js, v-for, html-rendering

I already checked about other questions, and have read about the “in-place patch” feature, so I tried to add a key to the v-for but still without success, can someone help me?

Here is my current code:

```
// THE COMPONENT

Vue.component('host-query', {

    props : {
        "queryvalue" : { type : Object, default : {} },        
    },

    template :  '<div class="input-group">' +
                    '<input class="form-control input-sm col-sm-2" v-bind:class="{ wrongInput : inputError }" v-bind:value="setInput(queryvalue)" @keyup="keyPressed" @input="updateInput($event.target.value)">' +
                    '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click="deleteQuery"> X </button> ' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</div>',

    data() {
        return {
            inputError : false,
            keyPressTimeout : null,
            inputValue : ''
        }
    },

    methods : {
        deleteQuery() {
            this.$emit('delete-query');
        },

        setInput(objValue) {
            if (!this.inputValue) {
                this.inputValue = JSON.stringify(objValue);
            }
            return this.inputValue;
        },

        keyPressed() {
            clearTimeout(this.keyPressTimeout);
            this.keyPressTimeout = setTimeout(this.validateAndUpdateInput, 1000);
        },

        validateAndUpdateInput() {
            let jsonValue = null;
            try {
                jsonValue = JSON.parse(this.inputValue);
                if (Object.keys(jsonValue).length == 1) {
                    this.inputError = false;
                    this.inputValue = '';
                    this.$emit('input', jsonValue);
                } else {
                    this.inputError = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                this.inputError = true;
            }
        },

        updateInput(value) {
            this.inputValue = value;
        }
    }
});



// HERE IS THE HTML

<div class="box host-selector-query-container" v-for="(queryObj, hostQueryIndex) in bundle.hostSelector" v-bind:key="hostQueryIndex">
                                        <host-query v-model="queryObj.query"
                                                    v-bind:queryvalue="queryObj.query"
                                                    v-bind:index="hostQueryIndex"
                                                    @delete-query="removeHostQuery(bundle, hostQueryIndex)">
                                        </host-query>
                                    </div>


// AND THE DELETE QUERY FUNCTION

removeHostQuery (bundle, index) {            
            bundle.hostSelector.splice(index, 1);            
        },
```

I console logged the value of the array before and after the splice, and the right elements are being removed, but in the display shows wrong, always last element removed, what am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `key`. When you use your loop's index as the `key`, you tell Vue that your elements are identified by their index.

When you remove an item of your array, you shift every index from the removal point up by one, which means only one index disappears from the array: the last one.

Since Vue is identifying your elements by index, the element with the last index is removed.

You should use as key an attribute which **uniquely** identifies the element, not the index.

Comment: the property query inside queryObj is unique, is a string. Maybe can I use: v-bind:key="queryObj.query" it will resolve to the property query of queryObj? Or do I need some special syntax? New to vue.js. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @TiagoM try using that as key, there's no need for special syntax in your case.

Comment: Okay will give it a try when I get back to work, and if works accept your answer, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Ayrton it worked, its weird though because I have another example where I don't bind the key and it works without any problem, however the elements of each for iteration are arrays and not objects, maybe that's why the removal works fine in that case without the v-bind:key? Would just like to understand it thanks

Comment: When you omit the key Vue just handles the element rendering for you. However, that doesn't always work when you have to manage state for the children, and the key is mandatory if those children are other Vue components

Comment: Yeah in the other case that is working without key, they are not Vue components they are arrays, each element is an array itself, maybe thats why vue can handle it, without binding the key, I am not sure